group by one column, get mode of another, and fill na with that particular mode
I am playing with the SpaceShipTitanic dataset on Kaggle.
I have a df. I want to group by a column, find the mode of a second column based on the group, and fill all the np.NaN values in the group in that second column with the most common value.
I feel like I'm skirting around this and not getting to the answer.
I have tried .mask and .transform and .agg. I've used lambda functions and attempted to deal with indices, and I am not accomplishing what I want. I must not be putting the parts together properly
Here is a brief example.
Start with something like this.
df = 
         Passenger_Group    HomePlanet
1        1                  Earth
2        1                  Mars
3        1                  Earth
4        1                  NaN
5        2                  NaN
6        2                  Venus
7        3                  Ceres

Note that in the full dataset there are a lot more columns and rows, so I have to work around other column names.
The goal is to end up with a df that looks like this
df = 
         Passenger_Group    HomePlanet
1        1                  Earth
2        1                  Mars
3        1                  Earth
4        1                  Earth
5        2                  Venus
6        2                  Venus
7        3                  Ceres

I feel like this should be a simple command. Everything I try doesn't quite work, though.
What is a succinct pythonic way to do this?
